# Most efficient way to get a substring without exceeding the string length

Tags: java, substring

I am currently trying to turn a string into a digit using this code:

```
public static int getDigit(String whole, int sub) {
    int d = Integer.parseInt(whole.substring(sub, sub+1));
    print(Integer.toString(d));

    return d;
}
```

But when I try to get the last digit I run into an error, I know the reason but is there a way to overcome this, like an algorithm (efficient method) that executes this other than my example here:

```
public static int getDigit(String whole, int sub) {
    int d = 0;

    if (sub < whole.length())
        d = Integer.parseInt(whole.substring(sub, sub+1));
    else
        d = Integer.parseInt(whole.substring(sub));
    print(Integer.toString(d));

    return d;
}
```

NOTE: Please ignore any errors in the code as I haven't tested the second example. The first example obviously has errors.

Comment: remove the `else` part and it'll work. Further, you don't have to call `Integer.toString()` when you print an integer/int.

Comment: If `sub` is equal to the length of the string, then what output do you expect? It is pointing to after the end of the string; the digits have indices `0` to `whole.length() - 1`. There is no digit to be parsed after the end of the string.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile - `d` has not been initialized.

Comment: Either way I haven't tested the last example because it is an example Im just asking about how to overcome the substring issue, I know the reason it gives an error but is there an efficient way of dealing with this?

Comment: @alfasin im not directly printing using the system so I do.

Comment: @copeg an uninitialized `int` is set by default to zero, but I agree that it's bad practice to count on it.

Comment: @Daedric the first part of the comment didn't discuss printing at all - it's about the `ArryIndexOutOfBoundsException` you're getting - it's from the `else` part - simply remove it!

Comment: @alfasin no its not its about the most efficient method forget it I solved it.

Comment: @alfasin, `an uninitialized int is set by default to zero` yes but d is an uninitialized local variable and compiler should error out `local variable d may not have been initialized` due to [definite assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_assignment_analysis)

Comment: @Daedric doing `substring(sub, sub)` will always return an empty string or exception...

Comment: @Trobbins Because it is unnecessary?

Comment: If that's pseudo code you should mention it in the question. Further, this 'pseudo code' looks very much like Java and you even tagged it as 'java'. After reading your (bit rude) comments - I see that your question is not clear at all. Instead of being rude to people that try to help you, you can try and make your question clearer by explaining *what* is it exactly you're trying to do, explaining that this code is for demo only and should be treated as pseudo, etc. Good luck!

Comment: @copeg you're right, if you declare `d` (without assignment) and then try to access it - it will generate a compile-time error. That said, if you'll look at the current version of the code: modifying `int d = 0` to `int d` will not generate such an exception since `d` is getting assigned before it is accessed/returned. But again, you're right: in the previous version of the code `d` was used in the `if` condition which would generate a compilation error. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @copeg are you saying that an unidentified global variable will not run into errors because it is automatically equal to 0 / null? Because if that is the case its good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative (assuming you're expecting a single character as a 'digit') would be handling the character at the passed index, by pulling the `char` and converting it to an `int`.

This can be done with the `getNumericValue(char ch)` method from the [Character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)).

```
int d = Character.getNumericValue(whole.charAt(sub));
```